# Call JS class on button click and append content to the DOM

Tags: javascript, class, dom, javascript-objects

I created a form, where users are suppose to enter a name and when they click the button, the button will call a function which creates new object based on the class User and the function call the render method. This method will append the new user data to the DOM. When I console.log everything looks fine but when I try to append to the DOM, the new div appears and disappears immediately. This is my code:

```
<div id="users"></div>
  <form>
    <input type="text" name="fName" id="name" placeholder="fName">
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="email">
    <button>submit</button>
  </form>
```

```
function submitForm() {
    const name = document.getElementById('name').value;
    const email = document.getElementById('email').value;
    const user = new User(name,email);
    user.render();
}

class User {
    constructor(name, email){
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
    }

    render(){
        const renderHookId = document.getElementById('users');

        const newUser = document.createElement('div');
        newUser.innerHTML = `<h3>${this.name}</h3>
                            <p>${this.email}</p>`;

        renderHookId.append(newUser);
        console.log(this.name, this.email);
    }
}

const btn = document.querySelector('button');
btn.addEventListener('click', submitForm);
```

Any suggestions why doesn't it append to the DOM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're actually quite close to working code! All you need to do is make sure you cancel the default event when submitting to prevent posting the data and refreshing the page. See below.

```js
function submitForm(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const name = document.getElementById('name').value;
    const email = document.getElementById('email').value;
    const user = new User(name,email);
    user.render();
}

class User {
    constructor(name, email){
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
    }

    render(){
        const renderHookId = document.getElementById('users');

        const newUser = document.createElement('div');
        newUser.innerHTML = `<h3>${this.name}</h3>
                            <p>${this.email}</p>`;

        renderHookId.append(newUser);
        console.log(this.name, this.email);
    }
}

const btn = document.querySelector('button');
btn.addEventListener('click', submitForm);
```

```html
<div id="users"></div>
<form>
  <input type="text" name="fName" id="name" placeholder="fName">
  <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="email">
  <button>submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Nice answer Nick.